# Why do donors' names appear twice on the emailed acknoweldgement of their contribution?

Tags: civicontribute, receipts, system-workflow-messages

From a previous question/answer ([Why is the billing name missing from the contributions email receipt?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/29086/why-is-the-billing-name-missing-from-the-contributions-email-receipt)) I gather that our duplicated Billing Name might be due to a mistake in the System Work Flow Messages. But we haven't done any customization on any of the System Work Flow Messages.(None of them show an option to "Revert" to original.)  Where else should I be looking to find the source of the duplicate name?
[image]

CiviCRM 5.48.0 on WordPress Version 6.0

Comment: Can you check Address Display Format under Address Settings(Administer >> Localization >> Address Settings)?

Comment: Here is the Address Display Format:
{contact.address_name}
{contact.street_address}
{contact.supplemental_address_1}
{contact.supplemental_address_2}
{contact.supplemental_address_3}
{contact.city}{, }{contact.state_province}{ }{contact.postal_code}
{contact.country}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the note from @pradeep-nayak, I would guess that the template has two tokens that have the possibility to contain duplicate information:

{$billingName}
{$address}

The address token on your setup may be customized to also include the contact's name. In the comments, I see the display format but if you look at the mailing label format on that same screen, does it have {contact.addressee} in it? If so, that may be where the duplicate name information is popping up from.

Comment: Thank to RayWright for helping me logic through this.  I thought (incorrectly) that the display address template was supposed to include the contact name as well as the postal address.  Deleting [contact.address_name} from the Display Address Setting eliminated the duplicated contact name in the receipt.